# Use TextField Controller but only need a text field?

Tags: flutter, dart

I read the doc that states I need a `TextFieldController` to save state of child widgets that scroll off screen.

My problem is I using a Text widget ( totalbagels ) and it will not support controller. I do not need user to input text since I am providing + -  icon to increase and decrease quantity value and display that in Text widget totalbagels count..

I tried to replace Text widget with TextField which but I do not need text  input.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CounterWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class CounterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterWidgetState createState() => _CounterWidgetState();
}

class _CounterWidgetState extends State<CounterWidget> {
  int _ecounter = 0;

  int _bakerdoz = 0;

  int _totalbagels = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      //track increment   ~/ finds just total bager doz of 13
      // %  check total for multiple of 13 and return single
      // non bakers doz totals back
      // TB = 16     BDz = 1   and Bagels = 3 for example...

      _totalbagels++;
      _bakerdoz = (_totalbagels ~/ 13);
      _ecounter = (_totalbagels % 13);
    });
  }

  void _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      
      if (_totalbagels == 0) {

          // check if zero do not go into -1

      } else {
        _totalbagels--;
        _bakerdoz = (_totalbagels ~/ 13);
        _ecounter = (_totalbagels % 13);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      
      child: Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            color: Colors.black,
            iconSize: 25,
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          ),
          Text(
            '$_totalbagels',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
            color: Colors.black,
            iconSize: 25,
            onPressed: _decrementCounter,
          ),
          /* Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                'BDz:$_bakerdoz',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                ' TB=:$_totalbagels',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ), */
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is your `TextField`?

Comment: You need a ordinary var (like int or double) and set use Text(yourvar.toStrring()) in widget tree. and in yours +/- button increment/decrement thta var

Comment: In your code, use ${_totalbagels.toString()} and ${_bakerdoz.toString()}

Comment: Thanks for feedback.  tried these solutions did not seem to work.    I think a example code for displaying a var or int via widget that shows how to save widget data when it is distroided  when scroll off screen.   I am playing with Slivers to see if KeepAlive will work.

Comment: thanks fund answer at this stack link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067901/how-to-keep-state-on-scroll-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

1. You dont need to use material widget inside Material App, because the pared widget extends this attributes to children.
2. Use expanded in one of the widgets inside row, to avoid rendering overflow problems.
3. There is an issue that have been lately when you set a function directly inside a button.

When using:

```
onPressed() => _yourFunction;
```

Use instead:

```
onPressed(){
  yourFunction();
}
```

This will prevent running the function when building the widgets, i dont know why this is happening in the new updates, and i noticed that happens just with buttons.

4. Set the data to a Text.
5. Or if you want to use TextFormField, there is no need to set controller, just use initialData attribute.